# Как вызвать метод класса, являющегося элементом вектора

Tags: c++, vector, вектор

Имеется класс Test, в котором определяется вектор и заполняется элементами класса Student. При вызове метода класса Test я хочу вернуть этот вектор и вызвать метод из класса Student. Пробую таким образом,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Student
{
    void Print()
    {
        cout << "success!\n";
    }
};


class Test
{
    vector <Student> vec;

public:
    Test()
    {
        Student std;
        vec.insert(vec.end(), std);
        vec.insert(vec.end(), std);
        vec.insert(vec.end(), std);
    }

    vector <Student>* Get_vec()
    {
        return &vec;
    }

};


void main() {

    Test tst;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        tst.Get_vec()[i].Print();
    }
}
```

но получаю ошибку **E0135  class "std::vector>" не содержит члена "Print" test** .
Пробовал подобное с массивами, всё удалось, но с векторами не выходит.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вас спасет

```
vector <Student>& Get_vec()
{
    return vec;
}
```

Но вам @Сахарок уже рассказал, что к чему. Добавлю разве что, что можно и так:

```
tst.get_vec()->operator[](i).Print();
```

или так

```
(*tst.Get_vec())[i].Print();
```

Но я бы хотел высказать еще несколько замечаний... Например - не надо использовать одинаковые имена для разных сущностей, потом сами запутаетесь - я об имени `std` переменной `Student`.

Еще - `Print` надо делать открытым, раз уж вы обращаетесь к нему снаружи класса.

В вектор лучше элементы не вставлять, а добавлять - с помощью `push_back()`.

Comment: Cпасибо за развернутый ответ. Только-только начал работать с векторами.

Comment: Странно, что в Qt метод`T::method()` у объекта в векторе `vector<T>` можно вызвать только через
`vector->operator[](i).method();`. Обращение по `at(i)` не позволительно. Ругается, что `'this' argument to member function 'addAmount' has type 'const Position', but function is not marked const` Версия 5.12.2

Answer (score 2):

`Get_vec` возвращает указатель на массив, поэтому при обращении к содержимому указателя необходимо использовать либо оператор `->`, либо разыменовать указатель.
Корректный вызов в твоем случае

```
tst.get_vec()->at(i).Print();
```

Однако лучше вернуть ссылку на массив и тогда твой вызов будет работать корректно.

Лучший вариант - сделать публичную функцию, которая вызовет Print для всех элементов своего вектора студентов, а не получать неконстантный массив за его пределами.